# Ruby VIPS image.write_to_memory yields different results in different environments

Tags: ruby, ffi, vips

We need to open an image and write its pixels to memory, so a C library can further process it. We're doing this with the lines below:

```rb
image = Vips::Image.new_from_file(filename)
pixels_pointer = image.write_to_memory
```

However, it seems that what's written in memory differs per environment. We're testing this on a macOS High Sierra and on an Ubuntu Xenial via Docker, with `vips-8.8.0` and `ruby-vips (2.0.13)`. We've MD5-ed the result of writing to memory:

```
p Digest::MD5.hexdigest(pixels_pointer)
```

and here are the outcomes for both:

- macOS High Sierra: `141e9b6a84f4ca05a7699b33fc0ef808`
- Ubuntu Xenial via Docker: `019a568e40dcc41ac6496da06d29d723`

I have no clue why this is happening and where shall I look further. Any tip would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question at the same time in many places. It makes unnecessary work for volunteers who are trying to support free software. Duplicate of https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/195

Comment: I had not known where would people offer help regarding this 